# React Virtualised trouble understanding overscanIndicesGetter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm currently using React Virtualised to virtualise a list. The caveat of this, is that my list is actually a grid layout, my component return statement looks like the below:

So the list actually ends up rendering a grid format. screenshot below illustrates the output atm anyway.

```
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
```

Depending on how much space there is to work with. AutoResizer adjusts how many columns there is within my (dummy) grid and all is well with the world.

```
const getMaxItemsAmountPerRow = (rowWidth, itemWidth) => {
  return Math.max(Math.floor(rowWidth / itemWidth), 1);
};

const generateIndexesForRow = (rowIndex, rowWidth, itemWidth, itemsAmount) => {
  const result = [];
  const maxItemsPerRow = getMaxItemsAmountPerRow(rowWidth, itemWidth);
  const startIndex = rowIndex * maxItemsPerRow;

  for (
    let i = startIndex;
    i < Math.min(startIndex + maxItemsPerRow, itemsAmount);
    i += 1
  ) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
};

const getRowsAmount = (rowWidth, itemWidth, itemsAmount, hasMore) => {
  const maxItemsPerRow = getMaxItemsAmountPerRow(rowWidth, itemWidth);
  const returnVal = Math.ceil(itemsAmount / maxItemsPerRow) + (hasMore ? 1 : 0);
  return returnVal;
};

return (
<>
  <AutoSizer disableHeight>
    {({ width: rowWidth }) => {
      const rowCount = getRowsAmount(
        rowWidth,
        itemWidth,
        items.length,
        hasMore,
      );

      return (
        <InfiniteLoader
          ref={infiniteLoaderRef}
          rowCount={rowCount}
          isRowLoaded={({ index }) => {
            const indexes = generateIndexesForRow(
              index,
              rowWidth,
              itemWidth,
              items.length,
            );

            const allItemsLoaded = indexes.length > 0;
            return !hasMore || allItemsLoaded;
          }}
          loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
        >
          {({ onRowsRendered }) => (
            <WindowScroller>
              {({ registerChild }) => (
                <>
                  <List
                    height={calcGridHeight()}
                    width={rowWidth}
                    rowCount={rowCount}
                    overscanRowCount={96}
                    ref={registerChild}
                    rowHeight={itemHeight}
                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                    rowRenderer={({
                      index,
                      style,
                      key,
                      isVisible,
                      isScrolling,
                    }) => {
                      const itemsForRow = generateIndexesForRow(
                        index,
                        rowWidth,
                        itemWidth,
                        items.length,
                      ).map((itemIndex) => items[itemIndex]);

                      return (
                        <ListRow style={style} key={key} ref={gridRowRef}>
                          {itemsForRow.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                            <ListItem key={itemIndex}>
                              {children(
                                item,
                                isVisible,
                                isScrolling,
                                itemsForRow.length,
                              )}
                            </ListItem>
                          ))}
                        </ListRow>
                      );
                    }}
                    noRowsRenderer={noRowsRenderer}
                  />
                </>
              )}
            </WindowScroller>
          )}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      );
    }}
  </AutoSizer>
</>
```

);

The render prop of children calls up to another component which does the rendering of my items:

```
  const renderFunc = (item, isVisible, isScrolling) => {
    return isVisible ? (
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        item={item}
      />
    ) : (
      <DummyItem />
    );
  };
```

However, my `isVisible` variable which (is generated internally within react-virtualised) gets passed into the function appears to be returning false a little too early.

This results in the following behaviour when scrolling:

[image: visual of problem]

In other words, my overscan isn't eager enough even when scrolling slowly - such that `isVisible` takes too long to return true I strongly suspect this is due to my layout.

To cut to the chase, from reading around - (rightly or wrongly) I think the overscan indices getter potentially needs to be adjusted, see here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#overscanindicesgetter

however, clueless as I am, I can't make head nor tail of this documentation to understand exactly what its doing, and potentially what I'd need to do to resolve things to make my overscan a bit more eager. You'll notice overscanRowCount={96} has already been added to the List, and I would have thought that high number should have been more than enough additional html for the component to work with even at slow scroll speeds.. hence why I think potentially `overscanIndicesGetter` is the key to my problem.

Any help appreciated, even if its to help me get my head around the overscanIndicesGetter function and what its doing under the hood. I tried console.logging some of the internal variables but I was still none the wiser as it seems to fluctuate wildly in terms of its output.

Comment: I am not sure what was the question, but I guess you had a performance issue, and you waiting for improvements?

Answer (score 0):

1, Try to use other library then `react-virtualized`. I would suggest `[react-virtual][1]`. The boundle size is way smaller, and using `React.FC`. (Modern react). 
2, I am not sure if you should mix the `virtual-list`, and the `isVisible`.

**Solution:**

The structure like this:

```
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
[ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM] [ITEM]
```

Is a good start. In this case you also have to track the container `width`, and each `item` width.
Width this logic, you can follow the next steps:

- Track the `row` and `column` sizes. (`marshaledList`).
- Create a `rowVirtualizer` and `columnVirtualizer`. (depending on the `marshaledList`).
- Setup a `gap` between.
- Style the `list` and `grid`.
- Dislay the `rowVirtualizer` and `columnVirtualizer` elements.

Live demo (working on 20k elements): `https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-kepler-vh70n?file=/src/App.js:2501-2506`

Comment: Wondering is it possible to data fetch dynamic data from an api with this library? how do you work out when to fetch?

Comment: For sure it's possible. Just replace the `elements` for some `api` response (`useAsync, or some state handler but not a simple variable`), and display the `properties` of each item what you need.

Comment: @Squiggs does it help you?

Comment: unfortunately not, I couldn't get it working with dynamic paging with an async call for data. The demo on the docs also doesn't work.